# Close button behind battery icon on Paypal mobile checkout iPhone X

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, paypal, braintree

We are using braintree js sdk to do payments in our ionic app. When the paypal process starts a fullscreen  view opens which you cant close, because the X-Button is behind the battery icon of the iPhone X.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks for your help,

Malte

[Image of the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8adL.jpg)

Comment: Not sure what's going on there, but perhaps you'd like to try the new Native Checkout SDK instead, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/native-checkout/